# Access json data from a file and use it in python script

Tags: python, json, plotly

I have a json file which contains:

```
[{
    "id": "a1",
    "num": "1"
}, {
    "id": "a2",
    "num": "3"
}, {
    "id": "a3",
     "num": "2"
}]
```

I am using plotly to plot it,
Here is my code:
    import plotly.plotly as py
    import plotly.graph_objs as go
    import json
    from pprint import pprint

```
with open('output.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

    pprint(data)


  data = [go.Bar(
        x=['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
        y=[1,3,2]
        )]

  py.iplot(data, filename='basic-bar')
```

Instead of

```
x = ['a1', 'a2','a3']
y=[1,3,2]
```

I tried to access it via:

```
for key.value in data.items():
    print(key,value)
```

throws an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plotlyExample.py", line 11, in 
    for key.value in data.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

where I thought:

```
a1,a2,a3
```

will be keys and
1,3,2 will be values?

I would like to read it from the json file. I can see data has the output but don't know how I will use it.

Any pointer will be appreciated.

Comment: json.load('filename') is enough, no need to open it or anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to traverse data's list of dictionaries and return a new list.

```
data = [go.Bar(
    x=[x['id'] for x in data],
    y=[int(x['num']) for x in data]
)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to parse the json into the x and y lists before you create the graph

```
data = json.load(data_file)

# will yield x and y arrays
x = [i['id'] for i in data]
y = [int(i['num']) for i in data]
```

Since the values for your num key are strings, you should convert them to integers before plotting